# How to Swipe Away / Slide In a Side Menu In Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, slide, side-menu

In my app I've coded a side menu that looks like this: [image]

Here's the code that is called when I tap a menu button that's in some views:
[image]

How can I have the menu slide in to view (depending on where the user's dragging finger is) and swipe away? And also go away when I tap the dimmed view on the right.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is using the gesture recognizers in swift.

1. To tap and dismiss the menu control, use `UITapGestureRecognizer`, bind it with a selector method and dismiss the controller/ view you are presenting. Check out the link to apple documentation for TapGesture : [Guide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/handling_uikit_gestures/handling_tap_gestures)
2. For swipe gesture, add Swipe gesture `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` to the UIView, and write the dismiss method using slide animation for smooth UI. [Swipe Gesture Guide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/handling_uikit_gestures/handling_swipe_gestures)

Let me know if you need any more help.